# jConfirm dialog before Ajax call gets executed after Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So my jConfirm dialog pops up after the ajax call, even though its present before the ajax call. Anythoughts?

```
Here is the code snippet - 

if(jConfirm("Would you like to send a confirmation email ?")){
                                sendEmail = 'Y';
}
imsHTTP.ajax({type : "POST", url : url, data : params, async : true, dataType : "json", success : function(jdata,msg){
/*
*****
*/
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see nothing that prevent the AJAX call or to wait for input from the User before proceeding with the AJAX call. You might consider moving your AJAX call into your IF statement. This may not do it either. Can you execute a callback when a confirmation is completed?

Comment: Unless jConfirm is doing some form of time travel, you're not using it correctly.